# What's the difference between the ApplicationServices (root) IServiceProvider and an injected IServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a hard time understanding why the behaviour is different to apply the service locator pattern in the Startup Configure method when using the `IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices` in stead of `IServiceProvider`.

When I use `IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices` (which *sets the `IServiceProvider` that provides access to the **application**'s service container*) I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve scoped service '...' from root provider

In contrast, when I use the **injected** `IServiceProvider` directly it works like a charm:

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider sp)
{
  // 1 : resolving a scoped service directly from application services container
  // IServiceProvider throws 'Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider'
  var test1 = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IMyScopedService>();

  // 2 : works like a charm 
  var test2 = sp.GetRequiredService<IMyScopedService>();

  // 3 : also works like a charm
  var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
  var test3 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyScopedService>();
}
```

**Why is this? Why does the injected `IServiceProvider` behave like it has "service scope" and `IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices` like it has a sort of "application scope" outside of service scopes?**

In a way *the injected `IServiceProvider` works the same as creating a scope first with `IApplicationBuilder` and only then resolving the scoped service from the scope's service provider*.

My head is spinning now.

Obviously it seems that the scope of `IApplicationBuilder` (does one name it like this?) is outside of service scopes. But when I look up [IApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.iapplicationbuilder.applicationservices?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_IApplicationBuilder_ApplicationServices) I can't find anything about the root provider.

**Can anyone clarify this?** Did I miss an obvious beginners tutorial somewhere that explains this root provider or application's service container?

Comment: How did you register your `IMyScopedService`?

Comment: I'm guessing a scope is created for Configure() and the IServiceProvider refers to it

Comment: Maybe, but also, what lifetime of object did he define?

Comment: @Nenad If you see "Cannot resolve **scoped** service ..." then this is caused by a scoped lifetime

Comment: @SirRufo so transient would write "Cannot resolve transient service..."?

Comment: @Nenad  registering in Configureservices was :  services.AddScoped<IMyScopedService, MyService>();

Comment: I find the behavior you are showing extremely peculiar. `Configure` method is part of `Startup` and called just once. I, therefore, consider this method to be similar to a "singleton." This idea is strengthened by the fact that `.ApplicationServices` is the root container. I would, therefore, expect that *only* singletons to be injectable into `Configure`, *and* that an injected `IServiceProvider` would be the root as well.  Considering that the injected `IServiceProvider` is disposed of, this is probably not a bug; but it's sure behavior I don't like to see from my DI Container.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by design.

ASP.NET runtime instantiate `IServiceProvider` in such way that it prohibits scoped services resolved from the root:

```cs
serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);
```

`app.ApplicationServices` is root `IServiceProvider`. `sp` is child of `app.ApplicationServices`.

You can check this using following line of code in `Immediate Window` of Visual Studio, while on a break point (that way you can access internal `ServiceProviderEngineScope` directly):

```cs
app.ApplicationServices == ((Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)sp).Engine.Root
// true
```

So only children of  `app.ApplicatoinServices` can resolve scoped services. One child `sp` was provided as input parameter, 2nd one you created manually.

**UPDATE:**
I gave a very detailed answer on MVC Core `ServiceProvider` and `Scope` default behavior [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67200499/186822).

Comment: This does unfortunately not work in dotnet 5 - Microsoft has apparently decided to make `ServiceProviderEngineScope` internal

Comment: @nover `ServiceProviderEngineScope` is internal in dotnet 3 as well. You have to execute that line of code in `Immediate Window`, during debugging, if you want to check it. I added additional description in the answer.