# NET CORE - AddScoped class that implements many interfaces, and get them by interface type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I would like to register class, that implements many interfaces, and then would be able to get instance of class, that implemements required interface. It must be scoped.

```
public class Car : ICanGoForward, ICanGoBackward
public class Bike : ICanGoForward
```

in startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<Car>();
services.AddScoped<Bike>();
```

and then

```
var vechicles = app.ApplicationServices.GetServices<ICanGoForward>()
```

should return instance of **Car** and **Bike**

**I know hot to make it work using .AddSingleton(), but in my case it must be Scoped**

```
services.AddSingleton<Car>();
services.AddSingleton<Bike>();
services.AddSingleton<ICanGoForward>(x=>x.GetRequiredService<Car>())
services.AddSingleton<ICanGoForward>(x=>x.GetRequiredService<Car>())
```

^ this dosn't work if I replace Singleton with Scoped.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Why doesn't this work? What is the observed behaviour?

Comment: Got System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ICanGoForward]' from root provider.

I based my knowledge on this article and it is said that if I want to use lamba expression it must be Singleton 

https://andrewlock.net/how-to-register-a-service-with-multiple-interfaces-for-in-asp-net-core-di/

Comment: Scoped lifetime services are created once per client request (connection).
There is not yet client request when you try to resolve the instances.

Comment: Do you need to work with ApplicationServices? This is the rootProvider which only works with singleton scope. (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080780) If you create a childscope it should work. Like this :
var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope(); var vechicles = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICanGoForward>();

Comment: @AardVark71 thank you for response. Where do you want to to create scope? Right before calling GetServices? If I do that, in other place where instance of this interface is injected by constructor (like in controller) instance will not be the same.

Comment: @Thibaut Thank you for reponse. So how should I define it, to have shared instance of class, that implements required interface in single scope?

Comment: Hi @BartekChyży,Did my answer help you?If so,could you accept as answer?If not,could you follow up to let me know?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddScoped<Car>();
services.AddScoped<Bike>();
services.AddScoped<ICanGoForward>(x => x.GetRequiredService<Bike>());
services.AddScoped<ICanGoForward>(x => x.GetRequiredService<Car>());          
services.AddScoped<ICanGoBackward>(x => x.GetRequiredService<Car>());

var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var vechicles = sp.GetService<IEnumerable<ICanGoForward>>();
```

Or try this in Configure method:

```
using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
{
    var sp = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var vechicles = sp.GetService<IEnumerable<ICanGoForward>>();
}
```